# Como criar um PowerShell Script para iniciar uma instancia EC2 e capturar o IP publico?

Tags: amazon-aws, powershell

gostaria de criar um PowerShell Script que execute os seguintes passos:

1 - Inicie uma Instância EC2 na AWS (Windows);

2 - Aguarde ela estar disponível para conexão remota. Enquanto aguarda, exibir uma mensagem de espera para o usuário;

3 - Assim que estiver disponível, pegar o IP Público (que será randomico);

4 - Iniciar o Remote Desktop para capturar essa Instância, usando esse IP;

Os passos 1 e 4 eu já consegui, mas os que mais tenho dificuldades são os passos 2 e 3. Já procurei aqui no Stackoverflow e também não achei.

Se alguem tiver algma idéia, eu seria muito grato.

Abraços

Comment: Quanto ao 2º passo não o posso ajudar, mas no 3º dê uma visto de olhos neste [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-StaticPublic-IP-09d7695c)

Comment: Obrigado, porém o endereço IP publico, seria da instância EC2 que esta na Amazon Web Service, e o Script iria rodar na maquina do usuário que iria captura-la via Remote Desktop.

Comment: Toda vez que se Para e Inicia a Instancia, ela pega um IP publico diferente.

Comment: Você está usando a aws cli?

Comment: Sim, atualmente a versão 1.11.162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o passo 2 voce pode usar os comandos wait, como `aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx` (use --query no passo 1 para capturar o instance id):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-running.html

Para o passo 3: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938971/list-public-ip-addresses-of-ec2-instances/24939787#24939787

Comment: Julio, perfeito !! matou a charada!! Ficou assim o Script final:

Comment: 1 - aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: 2 - msg * Aguarde um momento enquanto ligamos o computador remoto. Isso pode levar ate uns 5 minutos. Obrigado !!

Comment: 3 - aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: 4 - $ip = aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output text

Comment: 5 - mstsc /v:$ip

Comment: Boa, não manjo muito de powershell mas é isso ae! 